# WebBrowser não carrega css c#

Tags: c#, winforms, navegador-de-internet

Eu tentei criar um **Browser simples** e quando acabei apercebi me que não carrega *css* o site fica **horrível** parece um site **desatualizado**. :\

Alguém me pode ajudar?

Fotos do site, **se fizer jeito o código** deste pequeno browser terei todo o gosto em o dar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**código que se segue é o código do browser.**

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    webBrowser1.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;
    webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    webBrowser1.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = false;
    webBrowser1.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
}

private void url_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    bool link = true;
    bool dom = true;
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
    {
        for(int i =0;i<url.Text.Length;i++)
        {
            if(url.Text[i] == ' ' )
            {
                link = false;
            }

        }
        if(link == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < url.Text.Length-1; i++)
            {
                if (url.Text[i] == '.')
                {
                    dom = false;
                }

            }
            if(dom == false)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                url.Text = "https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=" + url.Text.Replace(" ", "+");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            url.Text = "https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=" + url.Text.Replace(" ", "+");
        }
        webBrowser1.Navigate(url.Text);
    }
}

private void F5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Refresh();
}

private void begin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.GoForward();
}

private void back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.GoBack();
}

private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    url.Text = Convert.ToString(webBrowser1.Url);
}
```

Comment: Olá Gonçalo, poderia mostrar um pouco do código?

Comment: claro vou ja atualizar a pergunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**O CSS esta funcionando sim**, o que ocorre é que simplesmente o Google esta carregando uma versão mais "leve" e "antiga" de seu site, isto porque ou ele não reconhece o seu navegador como um navegador moderno, ou pensa que ele é o Internet Explorer.

O componente `WebBrowser` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.8) vai usar o recurso do sistema operacional do usuário, através de ActiveX, no caso depende da versão do IE que o cliente tiver instalado, será o suporte que terá o teu componente, então se for carregar um site projetado com suporte para navegadores antigos, vai funcionar perfeitamente, caso contrário é impossível.

Se deseja uma engine/motor melhor, como o mesmo usado no Google Chrome, chamado Chromium, você pode experimentar este projeto:

- https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp

Se for usar com WinForms, instale via Nuget:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.WinForms/

---

Um exemplo do CefSharp (https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // deve ser chamado depois de InitializeComponent
        InitializeChromium();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void InitializeChromium()
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();

        // Inicia as configurações que você forneceu
        Cef.Initialize(settings);

        // Cria o componente
        chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com.br");

        // Adiciona para o form (ajuste aqui)
        this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
        chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        //Finaliza "quando fechar"
        Cef.Shutdown();
    }        
}
```

Comment: Usar o [WebView do Microsoft Edge](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview) também é interessante.

Comment: Boa dica @CypherPotato, infelizmente fica limitado ao Windows10, então esse limite ao sistema operacional pode ser um pouco incomodo, tendo em vista que tem gente que usa até mesmo win7, em casa e em empresas, mas a dica ainda sim é otima ;)